# SQL Server 2012 Stored procedure is getting deleted automatically

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am having a strange problem. One of my **stored procedure is getting dropped automatically**.
Its not that I am creating it in a wrong place. Every time I create the SP and execute my web page, it shows. After few min, if I execute the page again, it displays a error message which is due to missing SP.
I have tried recreating again and again, and everytime it repeats. I even did restart the machine (Windows Server 2008 R2), but no use. The same procedure is fine on my SQL Server instance on Windows 8 machine.
I tried the SQL Server Profiler, but of no use. Don't see any drop procedure.

Also for some strange reason, I am getting a lot of requests every second to my SQL Server which is hosting a dotnetnuke based website. Can someone help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE definition LIKE '%DROP%PROC%'` to see if you left a DROP command in another procedure. Also you could try looking at the [default trace](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10716/determining-how-a-schema-change-occurred/10718#10718)

Comment: Thanks Martin. I tried your sql, which did not return any info. However, tried the standard reports from management studio for schema changes, which did confirm the sp being dropped, but unable to get from where it was dropped. Also, I am very sure that I have not included any drop proc in any of my other code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just had this issue presented by another developer. It turned out that there was a `"DROP procedure"` included at the end of another SP.
To look for such hidden statement in another database SP, run a statement like

```
select OBJECT_NAME(sc.id), sc.* from syscomments sc where text like '%<name_of_SP>%'
```

where `<name_of_SP>` is the SP being dropped.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, and the issue was a missing GO in the DB script between a stored procedure create script and a drop of another stored procedure.
The solution was to add a GO between stored procedure 1 create and stored procedure 2 drop.
I referred to [Stored Procedure gets dropped randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497755/stored-procedure-gets-dropped-randomly).