# Stored Procedure gets dropped randomly

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

We have recently encountered a strange problem on our staging and production environments. We have run an update script to a stored procedure on SQL Server 2005, verified the new change, and started using it on our products. After sometime the same stored procedure has gone missing from the DB. This stored procedure is not being used by any other tasks except the one we are intending to use. We have checked every bit of code and deployment script, but cannot find a trace for just dropping the stored procedure.

This issue doesn't occur on our DEV and QA environments, but on Staging and Production only.

Could anybody help on this?

Kind Regards,

Mafaz

Comment: did you investigates your logs/event viewer?

Comment: Hi Jade, thanks for your suggestion, wasn't able to trace anything suspicious.

But hey Mr. @StuartLC, THANKS A BUNCH, I was able to trace the bug by going through the sys.sqlmodules which you had suggested, and as you had anticipated, the bug was that in the Deployment script, there was a missing of a GO keyword before the subsequent drop statement of the SP in question, in the creation of a previous SP, which had resulted in the inclusion of the DROP statement in the previous SP. Thanks a lot...Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've ruled out the obvious (e.g. deliberate sabotage), then I would suggest having a look through [`sys.sql_modules`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466130/can-you-search-sql-server-2005-stored-procedure-content/466188#466188) for a reference to the procedure - possibly there is an accidental slip like:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SYS.PROCEDURES WHERE NAME = 'Proc1')
  DROP PROCEDURE Proc1
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.Proc1
  AS
    ...

<< MISSING GO!

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SYS.PROCEDURES WHERE NAME = 'Proc2')
  DROP PROCEDURE Proc2
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.Proc2
  AS
  ...
```

i.e. in the Above, the `DROP PROCEDURE Proc2` code gets appended *INTO* the definition of the unrelated `Proc1` because of a missing `GO` at the end of the `Proc1` definition. Every time `Proc1` is run, it will drop proc `Proc2` (and the `if exists` will inconveniently hide an error if `Proc2` is already dropped).

Similarly, another common issue is leaving `GRANT EXEC` at the bottom of the `PROC` - if permissions are lax, this can destroy the performance of a procedure.

The best advice here is to execute applications with minimal permissions, so that it is not able to execute `DDL` such as `DROP` or `GRANT`. This way, the app will break when `Proc1` is executed, allowing you to quickly track down the offending code.

Comment: I didn't believe your answer, till it happened to me !!